# Why can alphabetical file permissions contain itself up to three times

Tags: permissions

When running `ls -al`, the beginning of the output starts with something like `drwxrwxr-x` In this string
I understand the following:

- `d` --> At the beginning of the string means directory
- `r` --> Means read permissions
- `w` --> Means Write permissions
- `x` --> And the x means execute permissions

What I am confused about though, is why does the `rwx` repeat multiple times throughout this string `drwxrwxr-x`??? I believe it has something to do with current user permissions, group permissions, and something else.... Any advice or knowledge would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: owner,  group,  others

Comment: What is the environment others?

Comment: others means everyone else (not the owner, not in group)

Comment: So in my particular case `drwxrwxr-x`, the other category only has read and execute permissions???

Comment: yes, that is what it means.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. The first set pertains to the owner, the second to the owner group, and the third to everyone else. By default, each user has their own user group. When a user creates a file, they are set as the owner and their user group is set as the owner group. Note that these are set according to effective user. Therefore, if you create something while you have elevated privileges (ex. using `sudo`) the owner will be the user `root` and the owner group will be the group `root`. Users can be added to user groups and ownership can be changed using `chown`.

---

Some recognition for @guiverc who posted in the comments while I was writting my answer.

Comment: So you're saying that if I created a file using touch the account I created the file with is the owner and they have their own user group?

Comment: yes, those are the default values for the owner and group.